# Nginx Puma and Rails 5 load test fails

Tags: mysql, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5, puma

We have a Rails 5 application with Nginx and puma. When we tested the application for performance most of the requests were not processed and we get 500, 502, 503 error. example we send 8000 requests concurrently out of which only 3500 (app.) processed and rest all failed wit 500, 502,503 error. We use defualt configuration of nginx and puma except the following changes:
nginx change : 
proxy_read_timeout 300;

Puma change :
worker 2
threads 16,64

When we increase the number of workers from 2 to 4 in puma the results were improved however we still get around 10% 500 error.

Server configuration : amazon Ec2 instance with quad core and 4 GB RAM.

I am new to PUMA and nginx.Is there any configuration is required to handle concurrent requests?

Also we noticed that when a worker started in PUMA the equivalent number of DB connections were created and not release by PUMA. (Database Mysql RDS) In DB config we have set 5 connection pool and hence the number connections hold are 5 * number of workers. This is not released at all and when we restart the puma then connections are released.

Comment: After increasing connection pool 500 error got resolved. However the RDS connection is not released at all. Example if we have 2 workes with 10 connection pool then 20 RDS connections were hold by application even it is not in use. Is there any config to control the RDS connection?